# disable update for wordpress plugin named Dropbox Folder Share

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I have found the following plugin. [Dropbox Folder Share](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dropbox-folder-share/)
which is licensed under the GNU General Public License.

In the plugin I have made some minor changes. mainly added my language. but i have also changed som other things.

How can I ensure that the plugin will not be updated. so I lose my changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nicest way to do it would be to hook into `'site_transient_update_plugins'`.

```
function so_filter_plugin_updates( $value ) {
    unset( $value->response['dropbox-folder-share/dropbox-folder-share.php'] );
    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'so_filter_plugin_updates' );
```

A hacky way to do it would be to change the version number in the plugin to something ridiculously high, like `9999.999`.